# Is there a measure for the 'degree' of cointegration

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Is there a standard (or maybe even intuitive?) way of ranking pairs of cointegrated time series so that one could make statements like the following:

```
series A is MOST cointegrated with series M
series A is NEXT MOST cointegrated with series Y
...
series A is NEXT, ... NEXT (i.e. LEAST) cointegrated with series J
```

Comment: Did you find a concrete answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Augmented Dickey–Fuller test is usually used for this purpose. Again, wikipedia does a decent treatment.

I would suggest using google for this before posting here. There is tons of information out there on cointegration.